# React + Material UI is it posible to change scrollbar to buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a component that shows a scrollable list of cards. Is it possible to change the scrollbar to buttons to move between the cards.
[Image of my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtunM.png)

Tis would be my code

```
<Box
        style={{
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          justifyContent: "space-around",
          overflow: "hidden",
          width: "70%",
          overflowX: "scroll",
        }}
      >
        <Grid container spacing={3} style={{ flexWrap: "nowrap" }}>
          {data.map((data, index) => {
            const { Title, Summary } = data;
            return (
              <Grid item>
                <Card sx={{ width: 300 }}>
                  <CardMedia
                    sx={{ height: 140 }}
                    image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
                    title="green iguana"
                  />
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                      {Title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                      {Summary}
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                </Card>
              </Grid>
            );
          })}
        </Grid>
      </Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will require some additional state management to track the current scroll position and methods to handle the scrolling action when the buttons are clicked.

1. Add State for Scroll Position: Use a state variable to keep track of the current horizontal scroll position.
2. Create Scroll Functions: Implement functions to handle the scrolling action when the buttons are clicked. These functions will change the scroll position of your container.
3. Add Buttons for Scrolling: Place buttons on either side of your card list that, when clicked, will trigger the scroll functions.
4. Apply Ref to the Scrollable Container: Use a ref in your scrollable container to programmatically change its scroll position.

Try this one:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Box, Grid, Card, CardMedia, CardContent, Typography, Button } from '@mui/material';

const MyComponent = ({ data }) => {
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
  const scrollContainerRef = useRef(null);

  const handleScroll = (direction) => {
    if (scrollContainerRef.current) {
      const currentScrollPosition = scrollContainerRef.current.scrollLeft;
      const scrollAmount = 300; // Adjust as needed for your card width + margin

      if (direction === 'left') {
        scrollContainerRef.current.scrollLeft = currentScrollPosition - scrollAmount;
      } else {
        scrollContainerRef.current.scrollLeft = currentScrollPosition + scrollAmount;
      }

      setScrollPosition(scrollContainerRef.current.scrollLeft);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box style={{ width: '70%', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Button onClick={() => handleScroll('left')}>Left</Button>
      <Box
        ref={scrollContainerRef}
        style={{
          overflow: 'hidden',
          overflowX: 'scroll',
          flexWrap: 'nowrap',
          flexGrow: 1
        }}
      >
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          {data.map((item, index) => {
            const { Title, Summary } = item;
            return (
              <Grid item key={index}>
                <Card sx={{ width: 300 }}>
                  {/* Card content */}
                </Card>
              </Grid>
            );
          })}
        </Grid>
      </Box>
      <Button onClick={() => handleScroll('right')}>Right</Button>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks @Batman, is there any way that the movement of the scroll is slow instead of instant?